# Gson can't parse my json date in java

Tags: java, json, date, gson

I'm trying to make some test for a java-ee application that uses rest, but when I tried to format some json with gson I got the following error:

`java.text.ParseException: Failed to parse date ["1489752692000']: Invalid time zone indicator '9'`

This happened when I initialized my Gson with `Gson gson = new Gson();`, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455123/gson-fails-to-parse-using-gsonbuilder-setdateformatyyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-sssz) on StackOverflow where the solution was to make a custom DateDeseriliazer class and intialize like this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new GsonDateFormatter()).create();
```

Here is my version of the DateDeserializer class:

```
public class GsonDateFormatter implements JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    private final DateFormat dateFormat;

    public GsonDateFormatter() {
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));
    }

    public synchronized Date deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement,Type type,JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) {
        try {
            return dateFormat.parse(jsonElement.getAsString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new JsonParseException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

But this only changes the error message to:

`java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1489752692000"`

So I'm not quite sure how to solve this now and I hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe merely `new Date(jsonElement.getAsLong())`?

Comment: `1489752692000` obviously is not of the format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'`, so why did you give that format?

Comment: @cricket_007 because I wasn't sure what format to put there and the other post used that format

Comment: Read the other post again. Look at their dates in the JSON strings.

Comment: @cricket_007 I saw that, but like I said, I didn't know what format mine was and I wasn't sure if that was the input format or something else

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv where would I put that?

Comment: You have what is called "milliseconds since epoch", and you don't need `SimpleDateFormat` for that unless you wanted to convert the number into a human-readable format as per the table in [`SimpleDateFormat` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: @DennisvanOpstal You don't need `SimpleDateFormat` here: you're trying to parse _number of ms since January 1, 1970_ using the given pattern. The pattern you're trying to use is used to parse strings like `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`. Just replace `dateFormat.parse` with `return new Date(jsonElement.getAsLong())`.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv that works, if you create an answer out of that comment, I'll accept it as answer

Comment: @cricket_007 Oh, okay, I think I was a bit too focussed on the example to see that as a possibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have what appears to be milliseconds since epoch.

It's recommended to use [`java.time` API now in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34444188/2308683) instead of `SimpleDateFormat`

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.timeZoneOffset;

// ... 

long epoch = Long.parseLong(jsonElement.getAsString()); // Or if you can do jsonElement.getAsLong()
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(epoch);
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneOffset.UTC); // 2017-03-17T12:11:32Z
```

---

But, in any case, you don't need `SimpleDateFormat` to return a `Date` from a long value.

```
public synchronized Date deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement,Type type,JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) {
    long epoch = jsonElement.getAsLong();
    return new Date(epoch);
 }
```

Comment: This just gives me red lines everywhere saying `Usage of API documented as @since 1.6+` and isn't  `jsonElement.getAsLong();` sufficient?

Comment: It is sufficient, yes. The import statements go at the top of the file, so not sure what else you are doing wrong unless you are not compiling with Java 8

Comment: The imports are where they belong on the top of the file (also with those red lines)

Comment: Like I said, if you can't import, then you aren't compiling against Java 8