# How to convert DateTime to Date?

Tags: java, android, datetime, simpledateformat

In the `Cotacoes` class, I have the `creation_date` field, it is a Date, but on the server it is a DateTime. Upon receiving JSON, the following error occurs:

```
java.text.ParseException: Failed to parse date ["2018-11-05T12:12:37.307']: No time zone indicator
```

How to solve this problem?
I use retrofit to make and receive calls from the server.

Cotacoes:

```
public class Cotacoes implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 842387749350567455L;
    @SerializedName("quotation_id")
    @Expose
    private int quotation_id;
    //private int transaction_id;
    @SerializedName("pecas")
    @Expose
    private List<Pecas> pecas;
    @SerializedName("creation_date")
    @Expose
    private Date creation_date;
   // private int duration;
    @SerializedName("brand")
    @Expose
    private String brand;
    @SerializedName("vehicle")
    @Expose
    private String vehicle;

....
getters and setters
}
```

Retrofit:

```
public class APIRetrofit {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://server.net/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .create();


    public static Retrofit getRetrofitClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface APIService {

    interface ReturnFutureCallback<T> {
        void onSuccess(T retorno);

        void onFailure(T retorno);
    }

    @POST("/cotacao")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<JsonQuotationResponse> listaCotacao(@Header("Authorization") String token, @Field("seller_company_id") String seller_company_id);

}
```

Comment: receive it as an string and later on where you need convert it into Date object 

For convert follow this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion

Comment: Have you tried SimpleDateFormat, or latest "java.time" package ? Did you know about date time patterns like 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss a' ?

Comment: Please post your json so i can tell you what pattern it use and i can also help you to write code for that

Comment: Yes, take a help. Explore by yourself as well.

Comment: i will give you exact solution if you post your json here

Comment: It looks like if you get it as a string, it works. As the friend said above, in the first comment.

Comment: You can use joda DateTime library.
Hope this link helps you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15333372

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I think, on sever, It's longtime or String, so creation_date field, it is a longtime or String

Answer (score 0):

You have to create JsonDeserializer for parsing DateTime to a customized Date object.

For more details you can refer the following links:

https://kylewbanks.com/blog/String-Date-Parsing-with-GSON-UTC-Time-Zone

[gson fails to parse using GsonBuilder.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455123/gson-fails-to-parse-using-gsonbuilder-setdateformatyyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-sssz)